# What does "<style>" refer to in Chrome developer tools "Styles" tab?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I can't find any references to this anywhere, in fact [Google seems to be willfully ignoring my use of quotes](https://www.google.com/search?q=chrome%20dev%20tools%20%22%3Cstyle%3E%22%20style%20in%20angle%20brackets&biw=2560&bih=1287&sxsrf=AOaemvJew7RDtZVTTTJMk5_TW9ffnzGM2g%3A1634143092668&ei=dAtnYZeeKOqEytMP9amiKA&ved=0ahUKEwiXqLO06cfzAhVqgnIEHfWUCAUQ4dUDCA0&uact=5&oq=chrome%20dev%20tools%20%22%3Cstyle%3E%22%20style%20in%20angle%20brackets&gs_lcp=Cgdnd3Mtd2l6EAM6BwgAEEcQsANKBAhBGABQxJkVWKDPFWCd0xVoAXACeACAAVeIAfYEkgEBOZgBAKABAcgBCMABAQ&sclient=gws-wiz) to force its inclusion -- `"<style>"`.  In the area where it would usually indicate which CSS file was providing the style on an element, instead it shows `<style>`:

[image]

This is on an element that clearly has no styles defined on itself:

[image]

So what does that mean? What is it referring to?

Comment: Probably some inline `<style>` element on the page.

Comment: It doesn't say it's inheriting -- and like I said (and image shows) there's no inline style on that element.

Comment: I mean `<style> .edit-action-dialog ... { ... } </style>`. Do `document.querySelectorAll("style")` and see if there are any..?

Comment: Ahh yes, that was it.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make the comment an answer:

It means there's a `<style>` element on the page with those rules, e.g.

```
<style>
.edit-action-dialog ... { ... }
</style>
```

You can use e.g. `document.querySelectorAll("style")` to enumerate those.